# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(token: string) => void

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular2 app, I have a class which contains some properties and I will be assigning values to them in components.

```
Injectable()
export class Globals {
    private token: string;
    private authorization: string;
    private roleUser: boolean;
    private roleAdmin: boolean;

    constructor(){}

    setToken(token: string){
        this.token = token;
    }
    getToken(){
        return this.token;
    }
}
```

In a component, when I set a string value to token in following way, I get the error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(token: string) => void

This is how I set the value in a controller.

```
this._globals.setToken = this._token; //this._token is a string
```

Why I am getting this error. I am just setting a string value which accepts a string parameter.

Comment: One of the values is actually a function, as the compiler says.

Comment: you've to pass value to the setToken function not just assign a value to the setToken function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a function for setting that private property and yet in your other component, you are setting it like a property . Use the function for updating `token`

```
this._globals.setToken(this._token);
```